# Horizontal Drop Down Menu Hover

Tags: html, css

I have tired build horizontal drop down menu from [this tuts](http://alistapart.com/article/horizdropdowns) and [demo](http://d.alistapart.com/horizdropdowns/horizontal.htm)

I want menu look like this :

[image]

I want to sub-menu appear to the right parent menu, http://alistapart.com/article/horizdropdowns#snippet4

Next step is the sub-menus. We want each sub-menu to appear to the right of its parent menu item when that item is hovered over.

```
li ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: 149px;
 top: 0;
 display: none;
}
```

But I have sub-menu not appear to the right of its parent menu looks like :

[image]

[here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jVtw/2/)

Comment: Your image is not loading - please embed again from source other than imagur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the existing style of your ul hidden list and add the following class : `subdrop-list`

Then add this CSS :

```
.subdrop-list {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
.subdrop-list ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4jVtw/3/

Answer (score 0):

The catalog item that have submenu in it must have position: relative, or position: absolute to make things appear relatively to it's offset top.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps - just add at the last css

```
 margin-top:80px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4jVtw/4/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `margin-top:35px;` instead of `top:0;`

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS of `.has_sub_sub ul` to `margin-top : -41px;` instead of `top : 0`

```
.sidebar #nav .has_sub ul .has_sub_sub ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 231px;
    width: 230px;
    margin-top: -41px;
    display: none;
    background: #efefef url("http://responsivewebinc.com/premium/macadmin/img/cream.png") repeat;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMDeM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/4jVtw/5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Horizontal Drop Down</title>

<script type="text/javascript" >
// JavaScript Document

startList = function() {
if (document.all&&document.getElementById) {
navRoot = document.getElementById("nav");
for (i=0; i<navRoot.childNodes.length; i++) {
node = navRoot.childNodes[i];
if (node.nodeName=="LI") {
node.onmouseover=function() {
this.className+=" over";
  }
  node.onmouseout=function() {
  this.className=this.className.replace(" over", "");
   }
   }
  }
 }
}
window.onload=startList;
</script>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font: 11px verdana;
}
ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
ul li {
    position: relative;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
    left: 149px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
ul li a {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #CCCCCC #CCCCCC -moz-use-text-color;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    color: #777777;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
* html ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 1%;
}
* html ul li a {
    height: 1%;
}
li:hover ul, li.over ul {
    display: block;

}

</style>
</head>
<body> 
<ul id="nav"> 
  <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li> 

  <li><a href="#">Catalog</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Attribute</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Attribute Group</a></li> 

    </ul> 
  </li> 

</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```